# How to load a package such that referring to symbols with namespace is needed?

Tags: r, package

How can I load a package but not put everything that it exports into the "main namespace"?

```
library(myPackage) # exports myVar
myVar            # This works, but I want it not to work
myPackage::myVar # This works, and I do want it to work
```

Comment: Does `myPackage:::myVar` do what you want?

Comment: @csgillespie `myPackage::myVar` already works, and so does `myVar`. The variable _is_ exported. But I don't want `myVar` to work, as I feel it litters the "main namespace" (even though it doesn't show up in `ls()`). I clarified the question.

Comment: Just to be clear, I have used three colons, and haven't loaded the package

Comment: @csgillespie Oh, I thought `:::` only worked to access non-exported variables of already loaded packages. That does it; thanks!

Comment: OK, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing the exported variables in a package, `::` is sufficient.  You don't need to load the package for this syntax to work. As `?":::"` points out in the first paragraph of the Details section, the triple colon suggested by @csgillespie is intended for inspecting internal variables not exported by a package.

Comment: I just assumed the OP had tried that and it didn't meet their requirement.